# API Routes throwing "Resource Not Found" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am creating an API wrapper for some old stored procedures alongside a new MVC 4 app. So far I have created this class:

```
public class Event
{
    public int ID;
    public DateTime DateBegin;
    public DateTime DateEnd;
    public DateTime TimeBegin;
    public int Duration;
    public string Name;
    public string Description;

    public static  IEnumerable<Event> GetEventSummary()  //List<Event> GetEventSummary()
    {
        List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
        DataTable thisDT = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string SprocName = "HE_GetEventSummary";
            SqlDataAdapter thisAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SprocName, connection);
            thisAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            thisAdapter.Fill(thisDT);
        }

        foreach(DataRow row in thisDT.Rows)
        {
            Event myEvent = new Event();
            myEvent.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["EventID"]);
            myEvent.DateBegin = Convert.ToDateTime(row["EventDateBegin"].ToString());
            myEvent.DateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(row["EventDateEnd"]);
            myEvent.TimeBegin = Convert.ToDateTime(row["EventTimeBegin"]);
            myEvent.Duration = Convert.ToInt32(row["Duration"]);
            myEvent.Name = row["EventName"].ToString();
            myEvent.Description = row["EventDesc"].ToString();

            events.Add(myEvent);
        }

        return (IEnumerable<Event>)events;
    }
}
```

Then I setup this empty API controller from the templates provided in Visual Studio:

```
public class EventController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/event
    public IEnumerable<HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event> Get()
    {
        return HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event.GetEventSummary();
        //return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/event/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/event
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/event/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/event/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

My Routes look like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Application", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

and the api routes:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" }
        );
    }
```

But when I visit `http://localhost:60009/api/event` (as specified by the comment in the api controller), I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /api/event

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What ever you are showing are MVC routes. So i think that is the reason why you are getting 404. Check whether, you are having API routes are not in WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: @ramiramilu Whoops, yeah I forgot to include those -sorry. Just added them.

Comment: are you able to go to /api/values/5 ??? or any other endpoint?

Comment: @ramiramilu No - so far I have been unable to find any api endpoints that work.

Comment: And one more thing, you need to specify id as optional parameter - defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } in your routes. Can you set that and let me know if it works.

Comment: @ramiramilu Made the change, but still no dice.

Comment: Do you have this line in Global.asax - GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);?

Comment: @ramiramilu I think that was my problem. I am having different issues now.

Comment: Note that you also don't need the defaults: new { action = "Get" } line. It will prevent Post from working for you

Comment: So have you resolved your problem with my comment?

Comment: @ramiramilu Actually, yes. Your comment, plus the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481678/fileloadexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code/23492413?noredirect=1#23492413 got me taken care of. If you will submit an answer to this question I'll mark you as accepted. Thanks!!!

Comment: @ramiramilu thanks again for all of your hep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to register Web API Routes in Global.asax in following way. Or else Web API routes will not be available to resolve requests.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```