# Stackoverflow exception in JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, json.net

I am using MongoDB + C# + Knockout. Recently I have added new column "SubmitCount" of data type "int" in my existing database (MongoDB).
When I query mongodb using C#, it is giving me Stackoverflow exception with no stack trace. I figured out it is giving me exception at:

```
var query = Query.EQ("Shelf", "Create");
var result = CollectionName.FindAs<BsonDocument>(query);
//Throwing exception at below line
var trialList = (from clnTrial in result
                          select new { TrialID = clnTrial["TrialID"].ToString(), CreatedBy = clnTrial["CreatedBy"].ToString() }).Distinct().ToList();
```

It was working properly before adding new column.

I searched a lot but found nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I just rerun the code removing "ToList()" now it is not giving exception. :-/. But I need ToList().

Comment: When you remove the `.ToList()`, does it still give the exception when you go to use the `trialList` variable? Without that call right there, you're delaying the iteration of all the elements until you actually use it.

Comment: And if all you're doing with the `trialList` variable is converting it to JSON, then you do not need to call `.ToList()` on it. You're fine passing an `IEnumerable` to JSON.NET and still get the JavaScript array object.

Comment: @krillgar, When I remove .ToList() it is not giving exception. I wonder why it started giving me exception after I added new column. Record count are same as earlier.

Comment: I understand that converting to JSON does not require ToList() but I need it for subsequent operations.

Comment: The `ToList` is most likely just the call causing the expression to be evaluated and any lazy Mongo queries to be executed. Some other remarks: don't think KnockoutJS is needed as a tag, there's nothing related to KO in the question (except for discourse context). Also, I'm afraid you'll have to help us reproduce the issue, or we can only help by guessing at the solution...

Comment: @Jeroen..Thanks for suggestion. I have removed the KO tag. Bythway I too afraid that I could not help you to reproduce the issue. I had existing Mongo DB..I added one column of data type 'int' and after that existing code start cribbing over on mentioned line.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit weird. But After trying all possible solutions, I noticed that NewtonSoft.JSON dll I was using was not of latest version. 
I updated DLL through Nuget and Bingo! it starts working again.

Some suggestion for updating NewtonSoft.JSON dll

- First uninstall old one and then update to latest one.
- If you get FileLoadException for referring two NewtonSoft.JSON dll of different version then try this solution [FileLoadException was unhandled by user code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481678/fileloadexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code)